# Redirecting to a website based on url entered in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect

So I run a small IIS server that hosts a website, for the sake of example let's call it `xyz.com`. I want to host `abc.com` on the same server. The directory to each website is something like:

```
c:\www\wwwroot\xyz\public_html\index.php
c:\www\wwwroot\abc\public_html\index.php
```

Where `index.php` is the main page of the website. How would I make it so that requests for `xyz.com` pulled up the homepage to `xyz.com` and the requests for `abc.com` pulled up `abc.com`?  I would do this through a DNS zone file, but since it's two different TLD's on the same static IP I'm a bit confused about how to handle it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [host headers in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

This will allow you host multiple websites on port 80, the default port for http.

DNS is used to tell the internet, where those sites are supposed to exist (the public facing ip address of your webserver).  Host headers in IIS, tell that traffic, where to find the files to serve up on the webserver, for that host (which gets passed along in the traffic).  You will also want to set index.php as the default page in IIS (I can't remember if it's there by default or not).

Comment: [This seems also to work with SSL](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html), though I never did by myself. For SSL I always used separate IP addresses.